# Accessing a component viewmodel from its containing viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, web-component

I'm experiencing with knockout.js components and require.js.
This is working well so far, but I'm struggling with the following.

Let's say I have one instance of my component in a very simple html page :

```
<div id="exams">
    <databound-exam-control></databound-exam-control>
</div>
```

From the containing viewmodel :

```
require(['knockout', 'viewModel', 'domReady!'], function (ko, viewModel) {
    ko.components.register('databound-exam-control', {
        viewModel: { require: 'databound-exam-control-viewmodel' },
        template: { require: 'text!databound-exam-control-view.html' }
    });

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

I would like to get the child viewmodel content to later save all the data of the page when I click a button.

For now I just trying to display the display the parent/child viewmodels in a **pre** tag :

```
<div>
    <pre data-bind="text: childViewModel()"></pre>
</div>
```

With the help of the containing viewmodel :

```
function childViewModel() {
        var model = ko.dataFor($('databound-exam-control').get(0).firstChild);
        return ko.toJSON(model, null, 2);
};
```

I get the following error during the call to *ko.dataFor*, probably because the the page is not completely rendered :

**Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.**

Is that it ? Or am I completelty missing the point here ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would say that it might be better to set up your main viewmodel to track those child models as you create them.  As a contrived example, you can check out: https://jsfiddle.net/timh06/91n3m25t/

Also instead of `ko.dataFor` you can check out the `ko.contextFor`, which should give access to the binding context of the element.

Answer (score 9):

The easier way to communicate between the parent viewmodel and the child component is by using parameters.

- create a new observable property in the parent view model, like `childViewModel = ko.observable()`
- pass it as parameter to the child component `<databound-exam-control params= "{modelForParent: childViewModel}">` Note that the parameter inside the child viewmodel will be known as `modelForParent`, and in the parent view model will be known as `childViewModel`
- in the viewmodel constructor for the component, in your `databound-exam-control-viewmodel.js` script, you receive the parameters as the only argument for your constructor. So, if your constructor looks like this: 
  `function SomeComponentViewModel(params)` you can access the parameter as `params.modelForParent`
- use the parameter to pass whichever information you need from the child componente to the parent component, for example: `params.modelForParent(createdChildViewModel)`.

Now, the parent component can acces the child view model using the `childViewModel` observable.

Using observables is just one possibility. You can do it in other ways. For example pass a callback as parameter, and execute that callback in the viewmodel constructor to return whatever you want to the parent. I sometimes use this pattern:

- create a register api callback in the parent, like this: `registerApi = function(api) { config.childApi = api }`
- pass this as parameter to the child component
- in the child view model constructor invoke the callback passing the child api

In this way, I can acces the api exposed by the child component like this: `config.childApi.aMethosExposedByTheChild()`

Important note: you must take into account that, as the child component loads asynchronously, the information exposed by the child is not immediately available.

Unless you need to use it immediately this isn't a problem. For example, in your case, it looks like you'll get information from the child viewmodel after the component has been loaded and the user has interacted with it, so that's not a problem.

If you need to access it as soon as possible you can use polling --- or better, expose a deferred (an example implementation: [$.Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)) to the child so that it can resolve it to let the parent veiw model know it's already available. This also happens when the child viewmodel depends on loading external resources by AJAX calls (for example to load a drop down list, or some other information existing on the server).

Another option, which I don't like, is that the parent viewmodel includes the whole child view model and passes it as parameter, so the parent viewmodel has full control on the child view model. Obviously this solution doesn't allow the component to be responsible for its own viewmodel, so there is a tight coupling between parent viewmodel and child component, which is not desirable.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I'll try all your suggestions and get back to you. I am also trying to use [knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox).

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where my parent component needed to have access to a child's view model for sorting. My parent layout code looks something like this

```html
<div class="parent-component">
    <!-- ... -->

    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: itemsSorted() as: 'item' }">
        <child-component params="item: item"></child-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is `itemsSorted()` relies on observables in the child component's view model, e.g.

```js
var ParentViewModel = function(items) {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observable(items);

    self.itemsSorted = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return self.items().sort(function(a, b) {
            // ERROR here: The timestamp() observable isn't present yet,
            // since ChildViewModel hasn't created the observable
            return a.timestamp() - b.timestamp();
        });
    });
};

var ChildViewModel = function(item) {
    self = this;

    self.timestamp = ko.observable(item.timestamp);
};
```

Because `itemsSorted()` doesn't contain view models until the layout is already complete, it's unable to use child observables.

---

### Solution

My solution was to create the child's view model within the parent, and then pass that down through a parameter:

```js
var ParentViewModel = function(items) {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray(items.map(function(item) {
        // Initialize view model in parent to allow for sorting
        return new ChildViewModel(item);
    }));

    self.itemsSorted = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return self.items().sort(function(a, b) {
            // This works, because ChildViewModel's observables are already instantiated
            return a.timestamp() - b.timestamp();
        });
    });
};

var ChildViewModel = function(item) {
    self = this;

    self.timestamp = ko.observable(item.timestamp);
};
```

Next, in the HTML, pass the view model to the component

```html
<div class="parent-component">
    <!-- ... -->

    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: itemsSorted(), as: 'viewModel' }">
        <child-component params="viewModel: viewModel"></child-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, in the component registration, modify the `child-component`'s view model to use the parent's instantiated version:

```js
ko.components.register('child-component', {
    template: /* ... */,
    viewModel: function(params) {
        // viewModel is already created by parent, pass into component
        return params.viewModel;
    },
});
```

Now `ParentViewModel` can create and use `ChildViewModel`'s attributes for sorting without needing to wait for an initial layout. The code in `ChildViewModel` isn't aware of the difference and doesn't need to be changed. This does couple the child component to the parent which isn't good encapsulation of the component, but it allows for immediate layout and use of child observables by the parent.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I control my viewmodel component instance from a higher level.

```js
//ViewModel for Component...
function ComponentViewModel(params) {
  const self = this;
  self.Message = ko.observable(params.Message);
};

//Register Component...
ko.components.register("my-component", {
    template: { element: "my-component-template" },
    viewModel: function (params) {
        return params.ViewModel; //Return the instance created on root (or wherever you instace your component)...
    }
}); 

//Principal ViewModel...
function RootViewModel() {
  const self = this;
  self.ComponentViewModel = ko.observable(new ComponentViewModel({
    Message: "Hello from component!" //Params for component go here...
  }));
};

ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel()  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<my-component params="ViewModel: ComponentViewModel"> </my-component>

<template id="my-component-template">
  <p data-bind="text: Message"> </p>
</template>
```